# JavaScript await not always working reliably on Firefox

Tags: javascript, async-await, html5-audio

I am experimenting with JavaScript’s `async` functions and the `await` keyword. I have created two promise functions to play an mp3 and to wait using `setTimeout`, and an `async` function to call them using the `await` keyword.

I was having trouble after playing a long mp3, and found that the same problem occurs if I wait too long. If I play a sound, wait for a while, then try to play a second sound, the second sound won’t play if the wait is too long, just under 3000 milliseconds. This is in Firefox, while Safari appears to be OK with this.

I have included a snippet, *but* the snippet works well, even in Firefox. I have included the same code online at https://resources.webcraft101.com/await-not-working.html and here it fails properly.

I cannot work out whether the problem lies with the function to play the sound, or something else.

```js
 function wait(delay) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
   setTimeout(()=>{
    resolve();
   },delay);
  });
 };

 function playSound(sound) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve,reject) {
   var audio=new Audio(sound);
   audio.addEventListener('ended',()=>{
    resolve();
   });
   audio.play();
  });
 };
 async function playAsync() {
  await playSound('https://resources.webcraft101.com/sounds/drums.mp3');
  console.log('after drums');
  await wait(5000); // 2992 kills it
  console.log('after wait');
  await playSound('https://resources.webcraft101.com/sounds/cuckoo.mp3');
  console.log('after cuckoo');
 }
 document.querySelector('button#play-async').onclick=playAsync;
```

```html
<button id="play-async">Async</button>
```

Comment: Both the snippet and the external resource are working for me in firefox.

Comment: @lawrence-witt You hear a cuckoo after the drum roll?

Comment: @lawrence-witt I just tried it in Developer Edition and it works there too. Don’t tell me that I will have to work through the addons …

Comment: Yes, and I see all the console logs.

Comment: @lawrence-witt That was quicker than I feared. It looks like the __Disable HTML5 Autoplay__ addon was interfering with it. I have emailed the author. Thanks for your help.